# C# adding to list object from checkbox

Tags: c#, winforms, list

I am sure that someone has asked this before, but I am not searching for the right terms or something because I just can't seem to find what I am looking for.

I have a class Packages:

```
class Packages
{
    string PackageID {get; set;}
    string PackageName { get; set; }
}
```

I have a list of packages in my context.

```
public class TransferJobContext
{
    public string ImportFile;
    public string WorkSheetName;
    public DataSet TransferData;
    public List<Packages> Packages = new List<Packages>();
}
```

I have a checkedListBox on my form that is bound to a datasource.  Here is the section of code where I get the values into the checkedListBox

```
using (var connection = my_DB.GetConnection())
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = null;
        dt = new DataTable();
        string CommandText = "SELECT ID, Name FROM TABLENAME WHERE UPPER(Import_File_Source) LIKE '%abc%' and STATUS = 1";

        SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(CommandText, connection);

        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dt.Load(rdr);
        cbPackages.DataSource = dt;
        cbPackages.ValueMember = "ID";
        cbPackages.DisplayMember = "Name";

    }
    catch (Exception E)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(E.Message.ToString());
    }
    connection.Close();
}
```

How do I add a new Package to the list when an item is checked using the value member and displaymember of the selected items?

**Edit:**  Ok maybe I am going about this completely wrong.  Instead of telling you what I have done, I'll tell you what I would like to happen.

I am presenting my user with a checkedlistbox that has a list of names with check boxes next to them.  They can select more than one.  This results in me having one or more ID(s) to use in my query and name(s) to use as a description.  I need to pass around with my context the one or many id/name combinations of my "Package".

What is the best what to capture the ID/Name combination of the selections the user made and pass them into my context?

Comment: Winforms? Web forms? Mvc?

Comment: @TheSolution I tagged winforms due to use of CheckedListBox

Comment: Yes Winforms, sorry I forget to add that - new to C# :)

Comment: Leslie, have you considered using properties rather than public members?

Comment: Can you show how you bind data to CheckedListBox? It does not have value and display members

Comment: I am open to any suggestion...like I said, new to C#...

Comment: @Leslie I think you are using simple ComboBox, not CheckedListBox as you wrote in question

Comment: well when I look at the object properties it says checkedlistbox and when I run the form i don't get a ComboBox, I get a list with check boxes next to it.

Answer (score 1):

**First:** Fetch existing Packages from your database:

```
public function GetPackages() as List<Package>
{
 using (var connection = my_DB.GetConnection())
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = null;
            dt = new DataTable();
            string CommandText = "SELECT ID, Name FROM TABLENAME WHERE UPPER(Import_File_Source) LIKE '%abc%' and STATUS = 1";

            SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(CommandText, connection);

             var packages = new List<Package>();
             using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
             {
             do while(reader.Read())
               {
               packages.Add(new Package({ID = reader.GetString(0), Name = reader.GetString(1)})
               }
             }

            cbPackages.DataSource = packages;
            cbPackages.ValueMember = "ID";
            cbPackages.DisplayMember = "Name";
            return packages;
        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(E.Message.ToString());
            return new List<Package>();
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
```

}

**Second:** 
Assign the fetched packages to the instance of your context:

```
yourContext.Packages = GetPackages();
```

**Third:** 
Fill the CheckedListBox with your packages:

```
cbPackages.DataSource = yourContext.Packages;
cbPackages.ValueMember = "ID";
cbPackages.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

**Finally:** After user input, get the checkedpackages and do whatever you want with them:

```
foreach (Package  item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
{
     MessageBox.Show(Package.ID);
     MessageBox.Show(Package.Name);
     //do whatever you want here e.g. pass it back to the context
}
```

**Sidenote:** I would suggest you to rename `Packages` to `Package`, `PackageID` to `ID` and `PackageName` to `Name` (As already proposed in the example code).

Comment: when exactly have I assigned the List to my checkedlistbox control? I don't think I have done anything like that??

Comment: @Leslie also showed how you can set the datasource accordingly. ;)

Comment: It looks like you are creating a new list - I already have the List in my context, I don't want to create a new list.  And I don't want to add all the ID/Name combinations to the list, I only want to add the ones they selected

Comment: @Leslie I changed my answer a bit. Hope it helps you better now. If it doesn't, I would be glad if you could post more code about how you handle your TransferJobContext.

Comment: I apologize for the delay in getting back to this.  Thank you for your help but I don't want my context to have all the package combinations, just the selected ones.  I will see if I can modify what you have shown to accomplish that.

Comment: @Leslie no worries. If you have any further questions, please let me know.